# AsyncTask with server connection

Tags: java, android

Hello everyone I have this problem, I had to make a AsyncTask because the connection to the service from IceCast error NetworkOnMainThreadException then as I read around I say you put a AsyncTask to solve the problem, or give privileges with

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

but does not work under any circumstances and it crashes my application without even telling me something error despite the try-catch ..
Can you give me an explanation of what?

Thanks in advance here is the code:

```
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import net.moraleboost.streamscraper.ScrapeException;
import net.moraleboost.streamscraper.Scraper;
import net.moraleboost.streamscraper.Stream;    
import net.moraleboost.streamscraper.scraper.IceCastScraper;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SwipeyTabsSampleActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private Button streamButton;

    private ImageButton playButton;

    private TextView textStreamed;
    private TextView textSong;

    private boolean isPlaying;

    private StreamingMediaPlayer audioStreamer;

    private static final String [] TITLES = {
            "Live Stream",
            "Palinsesto",
            "Programmi",
            "Eventi",
    };

    private SwipeyTabs mTabs;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipeytab);

            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            mTabs = (SwipeyTabs) findViewById(R.id.swipeytabs);

            SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter adapter = new SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter(this,
                            getSupportFragmentManager());
            mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            mTabs.setAdapter(adapter);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mTabs);
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

            Inizializza();

            new AsyncTaskProc().execute();

    }

    private void startStreamingAudio() {
            try { 
                    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
                    if ( audioStreamer != null) {
                            audioStreamer.interrupt();
                    }


                    audioStreamer = new StreamingMediaPlayer(this, textStreamed, playButton, streamButton,progressBar);
                    audioStreamer.startStreaming("http://r35798.ovh.net:8000/listen",1677, 214);
                    streamButton.setEnabled(false);
            } catch (IOException e) {                       
            }

    }
    private void Inizializza()
    {
            textStreamed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_kb_streamed);
            streamButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_stream);
            streamButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                            startStreamingAudio();
                    }});


            playButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_play);
            playButton.setEnabled(false);
            playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                            if (audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().isPlaying()) {
                                    audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().pause();
                                    playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
                            } else {
                                    audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().start();

                                    audioStreamer.startPlayProgressUpdater();
                                    playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
                            }
                            isPlaying = !isPlaying;
                    }});
    }
    private class SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
    SwipeyTabsAdapter {

            private final Context mContext;

            public SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
                    super(fm);

                    this.mContext = context;
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                    return SwipeyTabFragment.newInstance(TITLES[position]);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                    return TITLES.length;
            }

            public TextView getTab(final int position, SwipeyTabs root) {
                    TextView view = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                                    R.layout.swipey_tab_indicator, root, false);
                    view.setText(TITLES[position]);
                    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                            }
                    });

                    return view;
            }

    }


    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    //////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            menu.add("Uscita").setOnMenuItemClickListener(
                            new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                            "Uscita Programma", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            finish();
                                            System.exit(0);

                                            return true;
                                    }
                            });
            ;


            return true;
    }


    class AsyncTaskProc extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {


                    List<Stream> streams=null;
                    Scraper scraper = new IceCastScraper();

                    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                    try {
                            streams = scraper.scrape(new URI("@@@@@@"));
                    } catch (ScrapeException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                    textSong =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCurrentSong);

                    try {
                            for (Stream stream: streams) {

                                    textSong.setText((stream.getCurrentSong()));
                            }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }


                    return (null);
            }


    }
}
```

EDIT: I move Ui in OnPostExecute() now this is new logcat

```
010-30 21:22:03.535: E/Trace(4973): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973): Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory cannot be resolved to a type
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at net.htmlparser.jericho.LoggerFactory.determineDefaultLoggerProvider(LoggerFactory.java:51)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at net.htmlparser.jericho.LoggerFactory.getDefaultLoggerProvider(LoggerFactory.java:39)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at net.htmlparser.jericho.LoggerFactory.getLoggerProvider(LoggerFactory.java:35)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at net.htmlparser.jericho.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:27)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at net.htmlparser.jericho.Source.newLogger(Source.java:1645)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at net.htmlparser.jericho.Source.<init>(Source.java:109)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at net.moraleboost.streamscraper.parser.IceCastParser.parse(IceCastParser.java:67)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at net.moraleboost.streamscraper.scraper.IceCastScraper.scrape(IceCastScraper.java:65)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at com.uniradio.cesena.app.SwipeyTabsSampleActivity$AsyncTaskProc.doInBackground(SwipeyTabsSampleActivity.java:264)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at com.uniradio.cesena.app.SwipeyTabsSampleActivity$AsyncTaskProc.doInBackground(SwipeyTabsSampleActivity.java:1)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-30 21:22:05.145: E/AndroidRuntime(4973):     ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided your logcat error so I'm guessing, but I think the issue is as follows.

You are attempting to manipulate the UI from within `doInBackground` which will cause your app to crash.  Move any changes to the UI that your `AsyncTask` must perform into `onPostExecute`

for example:

```
textSong.setText((stream.getCurrentSong()));
```

Comment: Thanks, I do it protected void onPostExecute() { textSong =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCurrentSong); try { for (Stream stream: streams) { textSong.setText((stream.getCurrentSong())); } } catch (Exception e) { //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); } } BUT CRASH AT: streams = scraper.scrape(new URI("@@@@@")); HANDLER DON'T WORK

Answer (score 0):

**-** Keeping the `UI work on UI thread` and `Non-UI work on Non-UI` thread is a good practice but from the arrival of `HoneyComb` version on Android this became a law.

**-** Android application starts on the main thread that is the `DUI` (Dedicated UI thread).

**-** You should keep the Non-UI processor intensive work on the Non-UI thread.

**-** Use `Thread` with `Handler` to do it, or use specially crafted `AsyncTask` which is also known as **PainLess threading** in Android.

**Now problem in your case:**

**-** `doInBackground()` is the method which is **use to handle the Non-UI part**, and you are executing `textSong.setText((stream.getCurrentSong()));` in this itself. **This is the main cause of the Crashing of your application.**

**-** Use `onPostExecute()` method to do the **UI work**, so keep the **setting of Text in this method.**

Comment: Thanks, I do it 
      protected void onPostExecute()
  {

   textSong =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCurrentSong);

   try {
    for (Stream stream: streams) {

     textSong.setText((stream.getCurrentSong()));
    }
   } catch (Exception e) {
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }
   
  }

BUT CRASH AT:
streams = scraper.scrape(new URI("@@@@@"));
HANDLER DON'T WORK